# Error while trying to run the jar file in command prompt

Tags: eclipse, jar

My requirement is to run a eclipse java project in command prompt. I am using following program structure:
project name:parser
package name:xml
class name:Sample (with the main method)

I tried exporting the jar file by right clicking the project name-->export-->jar file-->gave the destination path for jar file->checked the Generate Manifest file and selected the main program(Sample.java).

Now in the command prompt i tried to run the jar file in the cmd using

```
java -jar myjar.jar.
```

And the error message I get is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: XML/Sample:
>   Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
>   Could not find the main class: XML.Sample. Program will exit.

I have been searching for a solution for a long time but failed to find one. I would be very thankful if someone could help me with this problem. Kindly excuse for any mistakes in my question as I am new to java coding. Thanks in advance

Comment: You compiled your Java class with Java7 but on the command line you are apparently using a different (previous) version.

Comment: I checked for the java version in cmd and found to be jdk1.6. Now I changed it to jd 1.7 by using set path=<location>  and Now my program got succesfuly executed. Thankyou so much for your suggestion.

Comment: But I also need to run another project that has 3 classes. But doing in a similar way I get the following error msg on cmd:                       "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/jdom/input/SAXBui
lder "   Kindly help me to solve this